# Verifying collection was passed

Tags: c#, moq

I am trying to verify a complex collection was passed into a method.

I can't seem to think of how to write the lambda to test against.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

```
var parameters = new List<NotificationParameter>()
{
    new NotificationParameter()
    {
        Key = "photoShootId",
        Value = 1,
    },
};

message.Verify(m => m.Load(It.Is<List<NotificationParameter>>(
        p => // ??? Ensure that 'p' and 'parameters' have
             //     the same elements and values for 'Key' and 'Value'
    )
));
```

Just passing in `parameters` to `verify` fails the test, so I would like to test against the `Key` and `Value` properties.

`p` above is of type `List<NotificationParameter>`.

Comment: what is the type of `p` here `NotificationParameter`, `List<NotificationParameter>` or `It.Is<List<NotificationParameter>>`? if it is `NotificationParameter` then `p => (p.Key == testP.Key &&  p.Value == testP.Value)` could work for you. if you are trying to compare the collection then `.All` could be used for the same.

Comment: @PushprajRuhal I have updated my question. How would I use `.All` in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `.All` which execute an expression on each of the element and return true if all returns true, so for your particular case we could write the condition as

```
message.Verify(m => m.Load(It.Is<List<NotificationParameter>>(
   pList => pList.All(p => parameters.Any(pTest => p.Key == pTest.Key &&  p.Value == pTest.Value))
    )
));
```

Other method is to use IEqualityComparer & SequenceEqual

eg

```
class NotificationParameterComparer : IEqualityComparer<NotificationParameter>
{
    public bool Equals(NotificationParameter x, NotificationParameter y)
    {
        if(x==null || y == null)
            return false;
        return x.Key == y.Key && x.Value == y.Value
    }

    public int GetHashCode(NotificationParameter parameter)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(parameter, null)) return 0;

        int hashKey = parameter.Key == null ? 0 : parameter.Key.GetHashCode();

        int hashValue = parameter.Value.GetHashCode();

        return hashKey ^ hashValue;
    }
}
```

then use it as

```
message.Verify(m => m.Load(It.Is<List<NotificationParameter>>(
    pList => pList.SequenceEqual(parameters, new NotificationParameterComparer())
    )
));
```

Comment: Thanks. I voted you as the answer because you added the method using `.All`

Answer (score 2):

To match the contents of a list one can use **SequenceEquals()** and an **IEqualityComparer<>**

```
public class NotificationParameter {
    public NotificationParameter(string key, int value) {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public interface IService {
    void Load(IEnumerable<NotificationParameter> parameters);
}

public class ClientClass {
    private readonly IService _service;
    public ClientClass(IService service) {
        _service = service;
    }
    public void Run(IEnumerable<NotificationParameter> parameters) {
        _service.Load(parameters);
    }
}


public class NotificationComparer : IEqualityComparer<NotificationParameter> {
    public bool Equals(NotificationParameter x, NotificationParameter y) {
        return Equals(x.Key, y.Key)
            && x.Value.Equals(y.Value);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(NotificationParameter obj) {
        return obj.Value.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}

private readonly static NotificationComparer Comparer = new NotificationComparer();


[TestMethod]
public void VerifyLoadCompareValues() {
    var parameters = new List<NotificationParameter> {
        new NotificationParameter("A", 1),
        new NotificationParameter("B", 2),
        new NotificationParameter("C", 3),
    };


    var expected = new List<NotificationParameter> {
        new NotificationParameter("A", 1),
        new NotificationParameter("B", 2),
        new NotificationParameter("C", 3),
    };


    var mockService = new Mock<IService>();
    var client = new ClientClass(mockService.Object);

    client.Run(parameters);

    mockService.Verify(mk => mk.Load(It.Is<IEnumerable<NotificationParameter>>( it=> it.SequenceEqual(expected,Comparer))));

}
```

If the order will not be the same then a helper method to sort and then compare can be used.

```
[TestMethod]
public void VerifyLoadCompareDifferentOrder() {
    var parameters = new List<NotificationParameter> {
        new NotificationParameter("A", 1),
        new NotificationParameter("B", 2),
        new NotificationParameter("C", 3),
    };


    var expected = new List<NotificationParameter> {
        new NotificationParameter("B", 2),
        new NotificationParameter("C", 3),
        new NotificationParameter("A", 1),
    };


    var mockService = new Mock<IService>();
    var client = new ClientClass(mockService.Object);

    client.Run(parameters);

    mockService.Verify(mk => mk.Load(It.Is<IEnumerable<NotificationParameter>>(it => AreSame(expected, it))));

}


private static bool AreSame(
    IEnumerable<NotificationParameter> expected,
    IEnumerable<NotificationParameter> actual
) {
    var ret = expected.OrderBy(e => e.Key).SequenceEqual(actual.OrderBy(a => a.Key), Comparer);
    return ret;
}
```